# Transparent Activity does not open with typical animation, just appears?

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, themes, transparent

I have a transparent activity defined using this theme:

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent.NoDim" parent="android:Theme.Translucent">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

And in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".Activity"
          android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent.NoDim">
</activity>
```

However since adding this theme to the Activity, when opened the Activity does not open using the normal animation (where the view expands to fill the screen), rather it just suddenly appears.

Any ideas on why, and a fix?

Thank you!